# How do I add a web site back to the new tab page in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I think I may have hit the X for a web site that I frequently visit. Now it won't show up in the New Tab page. How do I get it back?

It most certainly appears in the history. How do I force that site into my 'frequent sites'?

Comment: What do you mean? That suddenly a site you visited regular is not showing up in the frequently visited page anymore?

Answer (score 3):

If you press the 'x' on another icon, you get the option to 'restore all' at the bottom of the screen. Then you might have to weed out those you don't want shown.

Alternatively, you could change the view to 'shortcuts' instead of 'most visited' and manually add the sites you want displayed on the new tab.

Press the pencil in the bottom right corner and change the setting under 'Shortcuts'.

This is how it looks in Google Chrome 84.

[image: change from most visited to shortcuts]

Comment: There is no pencil icon. I searched for 'shortcuts' in settings and nothing was found. I have Version 84.0.4147.135 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: It's right on the new tab page, buttom right: https://imgur.com/HpjmKU2